# Как реализовать подобный круговой слайдер?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Я обычно использую slickslider или owlslider. Подскажите, в какую сторону смотреть чтобы реализовать подобную навигацию?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в чем конкретно у вас проблема? слайды вниз уходят, или стрелки в центре, или что? цифры какие то мб справа еще. О чем спрашиваете?

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от идеи. Вообще надо использовать CSS и псевдокласс :nth-child
Тут важно другое, чтобы вы сами представляли как логически это построить. Если такое представление есть у вас, то используйте :nth-child.
См.: http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child для построения на любом фреймворке Слайдера.